# MvcSiteMapProvider preservedRouteParameters Usage

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I have a route defined on my controller action
[Route("xxx/{xxxId:int}/yyy/{yyyId:int}/Details/{editable:bool}")]

I have used 'preservedRouteParameters' and managed get the breadcrumb showing

My mvcSiteMapNode is like this:
mvcSiteMapNode title="TheTitle" controller="yyy" action="Details" preservedRouteParameters="xxxId, yyyId, editable"

I'd like to have the breadcrumb url contain the Id for the previous stage. i.e. xxxId.

Can anyone help with how to achieve this?

---

[edit]
Having played with it a little more it seems that the problem I have is that my 'id' is not named consistently.

In the parent I have 'id' and the sub page I have 'xxxId'
Changing them both to be just 'id' seems to have worked.

Comment: Changing both to `Id` makes sense only if both of the `Id` parameters represent the same entity throughout the node ancestry. But this question is unanswerable unless you explain what you mean by "previous stage" and provide the configuration and routing for it.

Comment: Cheers. I altered the Id parameters to match and that did the trick. By  "previous stage" i meant previous node.